# Python multiple serial port slows down USB speed on Linux

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I am currently working on a software that use Python3 (pyserial) to interface with a lot of serial port (~24) on a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3+ Lite. The serial ports are interfaced using multiple FTDI4232H chips. We access the board through a Ethernet USB interface. All of these are connected to the only USB OTG port of the Compute Module.

What I noticed is that when all serial ports are open, even if there is no serial communication going on, the Ethernet speed slows down drastically. speedtest result goes from 198.78 Mbits/sec to 1.48 Mbits/s. When using ssh to access the device, everything is stuttery.

My guess is that there is a pre-allowed minimum data bandwidth for each Serial connection, but have no clues as how to fix this.

Thanks for your help!

Martin

EDIT: @AKX, here is a code example that reproduce the problem

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
from serial import Serial


QTY = 23
STOP_TEST_AFTER = 30


def serial_test(serial_port):
    serial_port = Serial(port=f"/dev/ttyUSB{serial_port}", baudrate=19200)
    timer = time.time()
    while time.time() - timer < STOP_TEST_AFTER:
        time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_list = []
    for i in range(0, QTY):
        new_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=serial_test, args=(i,))
        new_process.start()

    for proc in process_list:
        proc.join()
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a program that simply just opens all serial ports and then waits forever without doing anything with them? (My hunch is that something e.g. polls the serial ports all the time even if there's nothing to do, causing a bottleneck.)

Comment: Thanks for the MRE. What does e.g. `htop` look like when you run this? Is the CPU busy, e.g. IO waits? If possible, can you also `strace` the Python process (though you might want to switch that to use threads for ease of tracing) to see if it's being busy with the devices?

Comment: Also, what if you just simply `os.open("/dev/ttyUSBx", os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)` (as pyserial does) the devices? Same thing? (What about without `O_NONBLOCK`?)

Comment: @AKX, htop shows that running the process takes about 37 MB of RAM and doesn't really impact the CPU. With `os.open()`, I get the same slowdown, either with or without O_NONBLOCK.

Comment: Hm. Honestly you might want to ask this over at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or the RPi forums since I think this might be more an RPi bandwidth/peripheral specific problem. (If you can, try the same setup on a machine with multiple USB controllers/ports?)

Comment: Forgot to mention that `strace` doesn't show activity while the threads are in the while loop.

Comment: For those who bump into this question here, https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114782/122631 is the answer on RPI SE